# Swift 3 Reset all contents of the app

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to reset all contents of the application when user goes back to the home screen? Basically while users are using my app, certain view controllers save items in a list but instead of deleting all these items individually, I want to be able to reset the data like as though the users started the applications fresh.

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Would help if you showed the code on how you are handling the data start with. Otherwise its just a guessing game on what to tell you.

Comment: Presumably you have a reference to the data. What's hard about "resetting" it?

Comment: @MwcsMac  I'm wondering if theres a one liner that can reset the whole application regardless of how i handle the data..I want it to reset it to how the data would be as soon as u launch the app

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there is no automatic way to reset all contents. You must detect application goes to background event and manually delete all data.